# Registry subkey invisible?? C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

So I am attempting to implement a registry system into a program I am building. So far, the main of the program has no problems opening, editing, or deleting any of the values associated with this key.

However, my cleaning program does, and when I tell it to show me all subkeys using:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey (regappend + reg, true).GetSubKeyNames ();
```

It tells me the value does not exist, or is null, and so I cannot grab information from it as a result.

```
private static readonly string regappend = "SOFTWARE\\";
private static string reg = "EL\\Main";

// Malfunctioning code:

using (RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey (regappend + reg, true)) 
{
    if (myKey != null) 
    {
        foreach (string s in myKey.GetValueNames()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (s);
        }

        Console.WriteLine (myKey + "\n" + myKey.GetValue ("F") + "\n");
    }
}

// Working Code:

using (RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey (regappend + reg, true)) 
{
    if (myKey.GetValue ("F") != null) 
    {
        f = (string)myKey.GetValue ("F");

        if (debugmode == true) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (f);
        }
    }
}
```

Variables are the same throughout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're never checking if the value `"F"` exists...is this on purpose?

Comment: Yes and no. I am not checking at the moment because I am in the testing phase and *know* it exists. But mostly because I've yet to finish the infrastructure and didn't really think about it.

Comment: Are you running in 32 bit process on 64 bit machine? If so, then your key needs to be under: Software\\Wow6432Node\\El\\Main. Try creating the key there and run your program as is?

Comment: I am. But why is that exactly?

Comment: It's where 32-bit process keys live. If your 32-bit process writes a registry key to `hklm\software\el\main`, it will automatically be placed under the `wow6432` node. (WOW = Windows on Windows, but I don't understand it well enough to explain it). Similar to having 2 Program Files locations: `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program ran fine for me after I created the key using this code:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true))
{
    key.CreateSubKey("El\\Main").SetValue("F", "bar");
}
```

Note that, when viewing in Regedit, the key is actually located (on my machine) under:

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\El\Main
```

Possibly the reason you're not getting the value you expect is that you're looking in the wrong location in the registry.

Comment: This was my problem, as Rufus mentioned because I am using a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system it needs to read from SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\, not SOFTWARE\. It works now.